# How to get variables of any package in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, variables, plsql, package

I am trying to get variable_name, variable_type and comment of all variables from any package (it can be for example standard package, ULT_HTTP, etc). I want to get these informations by writting an request from all_source view.

Here is what i have tried :

```sql
select regexp_substr(text, '\w(\w|#|\$){0,127}', 1, 1) variable_name,regexp_substr(text, '\w(\w|#|\$){0,127}', 1, 2) variable_type,regexp_replace(regexp_substr(text, '--\s*.+', 1, 1, 'n'), '(^--\s*|$)') commentaire,text from all_source
where name = 'STANDARD' and type = 'PACKAGE' and regexp_like(text, '^\s*(\w(\w|#|\$){0,127})\s*+EXCEPTION(;|(\s+:=\s+.+;))', 'n');
```

With this request i can have only variables of type "EXCEPTION", so i want to have for any type.

Comment: Not sure what comment you're expecting - you seem to assume a `--`-style inline comment on the same line? - but for name/type have you looked at `all_identifiers`? [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=08e354d0e4412c3b1b8ebe1688ad16cf) - standard and utl_http might not be the best examples; and you might want to look at [PL/Scope](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adfns/plscope.html#GUID-24109CB5-7BB9-48B2-AD7A-39458AA13C0C) if this is for your own code.

Comment: Yes,sometimes with my request when i use utl_http like name = 'UTL_HTTP' i have some variables with comment on the same line. That is why i assume a -- style.